# How to use PHP constants in Mysqli prepared statements

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement, constants

I'm building an API with a bunch of db queries. To avoid repeating some pre established values in each query I created some PHP constants. However I'm not sure about the right way to include them in Mysqli prepared statements. I know that constants can't be passed by reference. So I wonder if I should create a variable for the query that includes the constants or if I could just pass the string directly with the constants to the prepare() function. So it is okay if I do it like this or should I create a variable and storing the string there prior to calling prepare()?

```
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT city FROM masters WHERE email = ? AND estado != '" . STATE_INACTIVE . "'");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $email );
```

VERSUS

```
$query = "SELECT city FROM masters WHERE email = ? AND estado != '" . STATE_INACTIVE . "'";
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $email );
```

Comment: Where's the difference between those two…?

Comment: `$stmt->bind_param("s", STATE_INACTIVE );` - why wouldn't that work?

Comment: @MatthewPage It doesn't work because you can't pass a constant by reference. Try it and you'll see.

Comment: @BrianDriscoll Thanks, checked up the docs and you're right.

Comment: Also, these ain't *PDO* statements…

Comment: @deceze yep, they're [mysqli]. If they were PDO then he could use bindParam for the first parameter and bindValue for the second, and use the constant.

Comment: I've edited the question to change PDO to Mysqli.

Comment: @BrianDriscoll is right, bound parameters are by reference so you can change a bound variable's value after you bind it. This allows you to execute the prepared statement many times in a loop, as you change the values. You don't have to re-bind the variables in every loop iteration.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you're using a constant value, you're not exposing yourself to potential SQL injection attacks by concatenating the value into your query. So, I think what you have is fine. Your other option would be to assign the constant value to a variable and bind it, like this:

```
$query = "SELECT city FROM masters WHERE email = ? AND estado != ?";
$inactiveState = STATE_INACTIVE;
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $email, $inactiveState);
```

It's worth pointing out as well here that this is mysqli, not PDO. If you were using PDO you could do this:

```
$query = "SELECT city FROM masters WHERE email = ? AND estado != ?";
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);
$stmt->bindParam(1, $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(2, STATE_INACTIVE, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Comment: Should it be `$stmt->bind_param("ss", $email, $inactiveState);` ? (notice the "ss")

Comment: PDO has a flexible non-bound `execute()` method which makes this a lot easier. You can pass in an ordinary `array`.